# substr in php. How to extract specific word from the path?

Tags: php, substring

How do I can extract word called `mygm` from the given path :

```
C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt
```

Here till `\cfng` path is constant and remaining can change.

Comment: So you want to retrieve the first directory after the constant string?

Comment: Yes exactly. suppose some one give me this path and tell extract mygm from this path how can i do in php

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to extract a specific string, or do you want to extract the value immediately after `cfng` and `aaa`?

Comment: You're not getting proper answers because your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes value immediatly after cfng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str='C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt';

$folders=explode('\\',$str);
$folder=$folders[5];
echo $folder;
```

Comment: Why down vote? Please explain. Or, better, test first and then give your opinion. Since first part is constant, this will work... tested...

Comment: This answer is actually pretty on target. Considering the `cfng` directory is a constant.

Comment: Perhaps he didnt create $str variable.

Comment: Yes who gave you down vote. This is exactly what i wanted. Thanks alot.

Comment: Np, now $str is there, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt';
$searchFor = '\mygm';
echo substr($url, strpos($url, $searchFor));
```

Comment: Thanks.. But not exactly what i wanted. Suppose there is mygmmm insted of mygm it is dynamic. i am not looking for search word in specific path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt';

$fixedStr = 'C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng';

$str =  trim(str_replace($fixedStr, '', $str),'\\');

$values = explode('\\',$str);

echo $values[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

As in Question it is told that till `cfng` path is constant.

So you can do an explode on `\` and print the next array element.

Explode can split a string into an array on a specific delimiter.

```
 $string = "C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt";

 $array = explode("\\", $string);

 echo $array[5];
```

you can print whole array contents like: `print_r($array)`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do is :

```
    $url = "C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt";

    $path = explode("\\", $string);

    echo $path[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = 'C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt';
$pattern = '/cfng\\\(.*?)\\\/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches))
    echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt";

$sub_str = substr($url,0,29);

echo $sub_str;

o/p : C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng
```

if u need only "mygm" you have to do below code

```
$sub_str = substr($url,-24,4);

echo $sub_str;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng\mygm\aaa\afc\Acharya.txt";
$var = substr($str,0,29);
echo $var;
o/p : C:\Program Files\abc\bcd\cfng
```

If you only you need "mygm", you can get it like this:

```
$var = substr($str,-24,4);
echo $var;
```

Comment: you can use above code when you know position and if you dont know position you can use function strstr() when you go with word in string ....